# Largest whole factor of an integer below another value

Tags: javascript, integer

I have an arbitrary value (being in the example `mx` that for example can be 4) and an integer (`x`) whose value can be anything from 4 to the integer limit. My goal is to find the largest factor of `x` that is smaller than `mx`. If `x` is prime, I can accept something for the next value larger. MY attempt so far has been along the lines of

```
function smFacBelowX(_x,mx){
    var x = _x;
    if((x%mx)==0) return mx;
    while(mx<x){
        if((x%2)>0) x--;
        x = x/2;
        console.log(_x,x,mx);
    }
    return x;
}
```

I will take a response in any language but would prefer JavaScript.

Comment: Is there an issue with your code? If not, Stack Overflow is not the right venue to discuss your code.

Comment: @FelixKling As is the code will return a value too small for some values. i will add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Albeit you don't say what's wrong I think it is the lack of integer arithmetic in JavaScript. You may try this for a beginning:

```
function X(_x,mx){
    var x = _x;
    if((x%mx)==0) return mx;
    while(mx<x){
        if((x%2)>0) x--;
        x = Math.floor(x/2);
        console.log(_x,x,mx);
    }
    return x;
}
```